# How do I iterate through NSSet<NSManagedObject *> in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This is my class... I am populating it fine when loading the XML via web service, however when I'm passing the object to another controller I can't get the list of purchase order items into an array I can put into a table.

```
@interface PORecord (CoreDataProperties)

+ (NSFetchRequest<PORecord *> *)fetchRequest;

@property (nonatomic) int64_t poActivityId;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<NSManagedObject *> *receivedRefReasons;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<NSManagedObject *> *purchaseOrderItems;

@end
```

Comment: `NSSet` doesn't have order. You might want to sort them according to a property? They have a custom class I guess, which one?

Comment: You can call [yourset allObjects] to get an array

Comment: @Pat_Morita I tried this

NSArray* groupsArray = [po.purchaseOrderItems allObjects];

and get

__NSArrayM purchaseOrderItems]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: How do you instantinate po and - inside of it - purchaseOrderItems?

Comment: GIPOGet returns NSMutableArray, that gets passed to (void)setPo:(PORecord *)po {}

and inside there I'm trying to access these
property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<NSManagedObject *> *receivedRefReasons;
property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<NSManagedObject *> *purchaseOrderItems;